# Tableau: stacked column with line

Tags: tableau-api, column-chart

I'm trying to graph workload (by day) stacking hours from tasks.  I'd like to add a line indicating daily capacity of the relevant resource. I have a table for tasks and table for daily resource capacity.

When adding capacity as an independent data source, I get an error indicating I need a relationship to the primary data source.

If I join the data (on date and resource), I can get a capacity line to show, but only by adding it to the secondary axis, which leads to mismatching of scales (unless I lock in the same maximum scale for both primary and secondary axes).  This works, but it's less than ideal :
a) it requires foreknowledge of maximum load,
b) lower usage resources barely move off the horizontal axis,
c) it seems to force the capacity line to use the same color palette as the column chart, plotting each time period with a different color.

Does anyone have any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

So both axes are hours? You can synchronise the two axes to make it dynamic. Just right click on the axis on the right and there should be a check box titled "synchronize dual axes". Check that and it will sync both of them and will responded to changes dynamically.

You can also then hide the axis marks for hours on the right to make it look better. Again right click the axis and deselect the "Show Header" option.

Comment: Thx @lampbob.  The Synchronize option was on the right axis.

Comment: I think I am still doing something wrong fundamentally - because it is forcing me to join my tasks table and capacity table to get this to work, my capacities are linked to task bars, and thus plotted as overlapping line segments, rather than just one clean series. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure how I did it, but I created a measure values shelf (which has also applied measure names to filters - with the capacity value selected as the filter) and the capacity no seems to be plotting as a single line....